# Should i be passing an entity DbContext by ref when sharing the same one between services / repositories

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reference, repository-pattern, dbcontext

My services take a DbContext in their constructor, and I have created a UnitOfWork class that contains all my services in order to make sure the same DbContext is used between them all.

**Sample of unitofwork class**

```
   private myEntities myContext

   public UnitOfWork()
    {
        myContext = new myEntities();
    }

    private RequestService requestService;
    public RequestService RequestService
    {
        get
        {
            if (requestService == null)
                requestService = new RequestService(myContext);

            return requestService;
        }

    }
```

By Using this unitofwork class all the DbContext for my services are now consistent and a change made in one service will appear in another.

However if i need to change the actual Entity context class then that does not get persisted across each service.

Below i have a "Refresh" method that re-initializes it (I need to refresh the context so i can have this class work with some legacy code).

```
    public void Refresh()
    {
        myContext = new myEntities();
    }
```

However my service classes DbContext objects aren't passed by ref so  the context is not set to a new instance of my entity class  and this results in the context not being refreshed.

So I think i can solve this by passing by ref as shown below

**Service class sample**

```
    MyEntities myContext;

    public RequestService(ref MyEntities myContext)
    {
        this.myContext = myContext;

    }
```

However i have seen people say you should not pass context classes by ref so i am curious if there is a better way out there and i am looking at this the wrong way?

**Edit**

Sorry turns out my proposed solution of passing by ref does not solve my problem, but i am still interested as to how i can update the entity context on the UnitOfWork class e.g. setting it to null and have that effect the service classes.

Comment: You misunderstand the `ref` keyword. The value can be passed back to the caller only during the method, not later on. In your case, passing by reference or not does not make any different.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858), that is you think that the solution is to pass the DbContext by ref, but you haven't described the problem you are encountering that the solution you presented may fix.  So my question is why do you `need to change the actual Entity context`?  What code requires this?

Answer (score 3):

Never ever should you share DbContext, by reference or as reference. It is not thread safe.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx

If you need an easy way to generate multiple DbContext, use ObjectPool from Parallel Extensions Extras.

**Update 1**

@tia is correct in saying that the private instance will not be updated when original changes:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pool1 = new ObjectPool<IDbConnection>(() => new SqlConnection("Data Source=server1"));
        var service = new Service(ref pool1);
        pool1 = new ObjectPool<IDbConnection>(() => new SqlConnection("Data Source=server2"));
        Console.WriteLine(service.Pool.GetObject().ConnectionString);
    }
}

class Service
{
    private ObjectPool<IDbConnection> connectionPool;

    public Service(ref ObjectPool<IDbConnection> pool) { this.connectionPool = pool; }

    public ObjectPool<IDbConnection> Pool { get { return connectionPool; }  }
}
```

Will print "Data Source=server 1", even if it would be a static field.

Enter [Monostate, a wicked pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/692285/Monostate-pattern), very similar to Singleton.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mop = new MonoObjectPool();
        mop.Pool = new ObjectPool<IDbConnection>(() => new SqlConnection("Data Source=server1"));
        var service = new Service();
        mop.Pool = new ObjectPool<IDbConnection>(() => new SqlConnection("Data Source=server2"));
        Console.WriteLine(service.Pool.GetObject().ConnectionString);
    }
}

internal class MonoObjectPool
{
    private static ObjectPool<IDbConnection> pool1;

    public ObjectPool<IDbConnection> Pool

    {
        get { return pool1; }
        set { pool1 = value; }
    }
}

class Service
{
    public ObjectPool<IDbConnection> Pool { get { return new MonoObjectPool().Pool; } }
}
```

I am getting rid of the constructor for service, as I can always get the current IDbConnection generator. There will always be only one instance of it, regardless how many times someone instantiates the MonoObjectPool.

**Update 2**

The other option might be to use [Autofac](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Getting-Started), but I am not too familiar with it, yet, so I can't give you an example how a type could get resolved in a service instance. Here is a simple example:

```
class Program
{

    private static IContainer container { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<DbCtx1>().As<IDbCtx>();
        container = builder.Build();

        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var dbctx = scope.Resolve<IDbCtx>();
            Console.WriteLine(dbctx.GetType());
        }

        builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<DbCtx2>().As<IDbCtx>();
        container = builder.Build();

        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var dbctx = scope.Resolve<IDbCtx>();
            Console.WriteLine(dbctx.GetType());
        }
    }
}

interface IDbCtx
{

}

class DbCtx1 : IDbCtx { }
class DbCtx2 : IDbCtx { }
```

**Update 3**

So going back to the Monostate, this works as expected:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mop = new MonoObjectPool();
        mop.Pool = new ObjectPool<IDbConnection>(() => new SqlConnection("Data Source=server1"));
        var service = new Service(mop);
        mop.Pool = new ObjectPool<IDbConnection>(() => new SqlConnection("Data Source=server2"));
        Console.WriteLine(service.Pool.GetObject().ConnectionString);
    }
}

internal class MonoObjectPool
{
    private static ObjectPool<IDbConnection> pool1;

    public ObjectPool<IDbConnection> Pool
    {
        get { return pool1; }
        set { pool1 = value; }
    }
}

class Service
{
    private MonoObjectPool myPool;
    public Service(MonoObjectPool pool) { myPool = pool; }
    public ObjectPool<IDbConnection> Pool { get { return myPool.Pool; } }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: imho, he is not trying to use multiple DbContext, but only one.

Comment: True, but if I had to guess, his services will not guarantee thread sequential execution, however, he has a need to have the same DbContext shared across all threads. So passing a DbContext by reference or as reference is not advisable. Put wrapping it in ObjectPool<T> is IMHO. I might be wrong thou, on my assumptions.